# Argparser and complex types

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I'd like to provide my user the possibility to add multiple complex objects, as example: a Library object would be:

- library_name
- library_number
- ...

To do so what I did is to set a parameter --library with an append action and add a type to the parameter so it reads it the right format, what lead to the following command line:
--library "library_name=test;library_number=5", the library type function will test and do the work, but this is not realy a pretty way to do it, there is any other way to do what I want ?

I wanted to use the nargs like this:

```
--library test 5
```

this look better to me however the type function I want to associate cannot be a complex one as it is runed on each values of the returned array!

Any idea?

---

I should explain a little bit more what I'm trying to do. I'm working on a workflow manager engine. This one specify a property file where are define all parameters and this parameter list is parsed to build the right argparse object.

As example I can define my library parameter as define before:
    library_name.name = ...
    library_name.help = ...
    library_name.type = str
    library_name.required = True

```
library_number.name = ...
library_number.help = ...
library_number.type = int
library_number.required = True 
...
```

But I want this object set as many as library the user want so I could add to those options an append action what would work but the user would have to provide all inputs in the right order:

```
--library-name lib1 --library-number 1 --library-name lib2 --library-number 2
```

but this is not that easy for the user, what I did is:

```
--library "name=lib1;number=1" --library "name=lib2;number=2"
```

but this is not "pretty", I would prefer something like this but I still want to check if this is the right format:

```
--library lib1 1 --library lib2 2
```

Is that clearer?

---

I should explain a bit more, I changed what you give me so the user can --library library-name=test library-number=5, so all fields are not necessary provided, however I would like some of them to be required, but to do so I need to know once all parameters are checked if the required ones have been settled

```
    class MiltipleParameters(object):
        def __init__(self, types):
            self.types = types
            self.index = None
            self.__name__ = "MiltipleParameters"
        def __call__(self, arg):
            parts = arg.split("=")
            if not self.types.has_key(parts[0]):
                raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError(parts[0] + " is an invalid flag! Available ones are: "+", ".join(self.types.keys()))
            try:
                value = self.types[parts[0]](parts[1])
            except:
                raise argparse.ArgumentTypeError("invalid " + self.types[parts[0]].__name__ + " value: '" + parts[1] + "' for sub parameter '" + parts[0] + "'")
            self.index = parts[0]
            return (parts[0], value)
```

this type take a hash table with the param_name:type, I could add the required field so it can be checked. But I do need to know when it is over to check if the required params where set.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a very simple state machine:

```
class NargsTypeChecker(object):
    def __init__(self, types):
        self.types = types
        self.index = 0
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.types[self.index].__name__
    def __call__(self, arg):
        value = self.types[self.index](arg)
        self.index = (self.index + 1) % len(self.types)
        return value
```

Used as:

```
parser.add_argument('--library', nargs=3, type=NargsTypeChecker((int, float, str)))
```

And some error outputs:

```
$python3 complex_type.py --library lib 1 3.6
Namespace(library=['lib', 1, 3.6])
$python3 complex_type.py --library lib other 3.6
usage: complex_type.py [-h] [--library LIBRARY LIBRARY LIBRARY]
complex_type.py: error: argument --library: invalid int value: 'other'
$python3 complex_type.py --library lib 2 other
usage: complex_type.py [-h] [--library LIBRARY LIBRARY LIBRARY]
complex_type.py: error: argument --library: invalid float value: 'other'
```

Comment: There is any way to make argarser display: usage: complex_type.py [-h] [--library INT FLOAT STR] instead of usage: complex_type.py [-h] [--library LIBRARY LIBRARY LIBRARY] ?

Comment: @user1595929 I doubt. AFAIK the documentation doesn't mention such an option, and giving a *very quick* read at the source I believe that `argparse` simply uses `metavar` for `nargs` times to obtain that help message.

Comment: That's too bad ... how the user will know which type of data it is!

Comment: @user1595929 Note that the `metavar` shouldn't be used to display the type of an argument. It should describe the *meaning* of the argument. E.g. `--library NAME VERSION BUILD_NUMBER`. If you want to add more information regarding an option then add that information in the `help`. Also note that in my solution, if the user gives the wrong type the error message will say which argument failed and which type was expected: `invalid float value: 'other'`

Comment: An other question, related to this one. I'd like to know the number of arguments within the NargsTypeChecker class provided by the user (not len(types) this is the number of arguments the user can possibly provide). How can that be done ? Thanks

Comment: @user1595929 Well, you can use the `index` attribute for that, since it basically counts the arguments passed.

Comment: What I would like is the total to know if the current one is the last one.

Answer (score 0):

If your library names contain no spaces, you could simply use one string for that, then do

```
library = argstring.split()
```

This will return a list `library` with `library[0]` as the name and `library[1]` as number.

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept as a format:  --library lib1:1 --library lib2:2

```
def libType(ls):
    name, num = ls.split(':')
    return name, int(num)

parser.add_argument("--library", action = "append", type=libType)
# you get: Namespace(library=[('lib1', 1), ('lib2', 2)])
```

If you prefer to stick with: --library lib1 1 --library lib2 2

```
parser.add_argument("--library", action = "append", nargs=2)
# you get: Namespace(library=[['lib1', '1'], ['lib2', '2']])
```

Then you have to perform additional type check to get int instead of str.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with a custom action:

```
import argparse

class LibAction(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        try: 
            lib = {'name': values[0], 'type': int(values[1])}
            if namespace.library:
                namespace.library.append(lib)
            else:
                namespace.library=[lib]
        except ValueError:
             parser.error("Problem with library: %s is not int"%(values[1])) 

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--library", action = LibAction, nargs=2)
args = parser.parse_args()
print args
```

You obtain:

```
Namespace(library=[{'type': 1, 'name': 'lib1'}, {'type': 2, 'name': 'lib2'}])
```

and some error handling if you use: --library libA a